# Creating an object of the same class as the parameterized type

Tags: java, generics, parameterized-types

Here's the code:

```
package Fabrika.Trake;
import Vozila.*;

public class Traka<T extends Vozilo> extends Thread
{
    protected int vrijemeRada;
    ...

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            //I want to create the object here
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's say I have a class called *Auto* which extends *Vozilo*.

I'd like to know if there is a way of constructing an object of type *T* **without using reflection**. Something like:

```
T object = new T();
```

This, of course, is completely incorrect, but it just serves as an illustration of what I'd like to do. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with just the generic type `T`.

To create an instance you need a `Class` instance.

E.g.:

```
public class Traka<T extends Vozilo> extends Thread
{
    protected int vrijemeRada;
    ...

    private Class<T> type;

    public Traka(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            T newInstance = type.newInstace(); // this uses the default constructor
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Traka<Auto> autoTraka = new Traka(Auto.class);
```

The problem is that the generic type information `T` is erased at runtime. Therefore you need a `Class` instance to represent the type at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [type token](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html).

```
public class Traka<T extends Vozilo> extends Thread
{
    private Class<T> type;
    protected int vrijemeRada;
    ...

    public Traka(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
   }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            //I want to create the object here
            T object = type.newInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

This works - of course - only with constructors that have a known number of arguments. My example uses a no-arg constructor.

And: Do not extend `Thread`! Implement `Runnable` instead. And then uses those runnables, wherever you need them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special pattern for this: pass `Class` instance to the constructor of `Traka`, store it in a private variable, and the use that class to instantiate new objects, like this:

```
public class Traka<T extends Vozilo> extends Thread {
    private Class<T> theClass;
    public Traka(Class<T> theClass) {
        this.theClass = theClass;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            T inst = theClass.newInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: In case you were wondering why `Class` became parameterized in Java 5, the pattern above is the answer.